# I am trying to print all the items under class in this excel csv type document but I keep getting an attribute error

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I try this code;

```
import pandas as pd
breastcancer=pd.read_excel("breastCancer.xlsx")
print(breastcancer.Class)
```

I get an attribute error.

If I use this;

```
import pandas as pd
breastcancer=pd.read_excel("breastCancer.xlsx")
print(breastcancer['Class'])
```

I get a Key Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there is no column called `Class` in your spreadsheet. You need to spell it exactly, using the same case (e.g. if it's `CLASS` in the spreadsheet you can't access it using `breastcancer['class']`).